# Cannot press ctrl + alt + left + up simultaneously to switch between workspaces

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, compiz, workspaces

By default, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+(<kbd>up</kbd>xor<kbd>down</kbd>)or(<kbd>left</kbd>xor<kbd>right</kbd>) is used to switch between workspaces, but why doesn't <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> work for switching workspaces from number four to number one?

Comment: I use your hint for about two yrs, but I am just curious about the reason. ;-)

Comment: Would you insist on sticking to the key combination? something can be arranged with Ctrl+Shift+Numpad7 (which is upper left on numpad) etc. would that work?

Comment: Doesn't work for switching between workspaces.

Comment: Nono, I know, but it could be made to work...with a script, but really, it does work as mentioned in the answer :)

Comment: Ha, nice answer, but I don't think it is better than press them discretely.

Answer (score 2):

Mine works perfectly this way . Hitting both arrows switch to desired workspace.

Obs: Using Unity

[image]

Comment: Inclusive the small animation when switching desktop desktop display oriented arrow diagonally .

Comment: BTW did you notice the 12.04 tag? it might not work on 12.04?

Comment: 12.04 LTS uses Compiz rather than Metacity, so I think the solution might vary between different versions.

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia  , there was no such tag before , must be edited.

Comment: Sorry for that, I forgot that Ubuntu change the compositing window manager.